# Handler to detect Save event on Office Addin API

Tags: ms-office, office-js, outlook-addin, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

In [`Office.AppointmentCompose`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/outlook/office.appointmentcompose?view=outlook-js-preview) interface from Microsoft Office Addin JS API, is there any handler to detect when the user clicks the Save button or when presses `CTRL+S`, in an Outlook Event?

[image]

I found [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/office/office.addincommands.event?view=common-js-preview), but this is only applicable to buttons inside the Add-in

```js
// In this example, consider a button defined in an add-in manifest as follows:
//<Control xsi:type="Button" id="eventTestButton">
//    <Label resid="eventButtonLabel" />
//    <Tooltip resid="eventButtonTooltip" />
//    <Supertip>
//        <Title resid="eventSuperTipTitle" />
//        <Description resid="eventSuperTipDescription" />
//    </Supertip>
//    <Icon>
//        <bt:Image size="16" resid="blue-icon-16" />
//        <bt:Image size="32" resid="blue-icon-32" />
//        <bt:Image size="80" resid="blue-icon-80" />
//    </Icon>
//    <Action xsi:type="ExecuteFunction">
//        <FunctionName>testEventObject</FunctionName>
//    </Action>
//</Control>

// The button has an id attribute set to eventTestButton, and will invoke
// the testEventObject function defined in the add-in.
// That function looks like this:
function testEventObject(event) {
    // The event object implements the Event interface.

    // This value will be "eventTestButton".
    var buttonId = event.source.id;

    // Signal to the host app that processing is complete.
    event.completed();
}
```

I also found this [list](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/reference/objectmodel/preview-requirement-set/office.context.mailbox.item#events) of events, but they don't include `save` event.

Comment: There is currently no 'save' event.  Could you tell us more about the scenario? Would something like on-send be an alternative? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/outlook/outlook-on-send-addins?tabs=windows

Comment: @OutlookAdd-insTeam-MSFT I would like to send some data to a server, said data fetched from the Outlook event, and I would like to have the latest updated data on the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is there any handler to detect when the user clicks the Save button or when presses CTRL+S, in an Outlook Event?

No, there is no such events available for Office web add-ins.

You may consider developing a VSTO based add-in where you could repurpose ribbon buttons, see [Temporarily Repurpose Commands on the Office Fluent Ribbon](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2007/bb462633(v=office.12)?redirectedfrom=MSDN) for more information.

Answer (score 2):

Currently the feature: save event, you requested, is not a part of the product. We track Outlook add-in feature requests on our [Tech Community Page](https://aka.ms/M365dev-suggestions). Please submit your request there and choose the appropriate label(s). Feature requests on Tech Community are considered, when we go through our planning process.

Comment: Thanks, [done it](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-365-developer-platform/handler-to-detect-save-event-on-office-addin-api/idi-p/3244812#M789).